# Using sed to separate pattern from stream

Tags: regex, bash, file, unix, sed

I have a file that has log entries on each line like:

```
request country_US url=http://example.com/us/id=6546456 {response_time 1000 msec} 
request country_UK url=http://example.com/uk/id=1242423 {response_time 60 msec}
```

Right now I'm using sed to process this file and separate the response time like so:

```
sed -e 's/.*\(response_time \S\+\).*/\1/p' -e 's/'
```

That transforms each line to

```
response_time 1000
response_time 60
```

Right now I would like to separate also the country prefix and get processed lines like so:

```
US 1000
UK 60
```

How should i modify my sed command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility which is pretty much in the sence of your original version is:

```
sed -e 's/.*country_\(\S\+\).*response_time\( \S\+\).*/\1\2/' file
US 1000
UK 60
```

For the future I can only recommend http://vimregex.com/ . I always found it being extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^request country_\([^ ]*\).*response_time \([0-9]*\) msec.*$/\1 \2/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your `sed` expression a bit to get the desired result.  Saying:

```
sed -r 's/.*country_(\S+).*response_time ([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/' filename
```

would return the following for your sample input:

```
US 1000
UK 60
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/response_time/ {split($2,a,"_");print a[2],$(NF-1)}' file
US 1000
UK 60
```

---

If all line does have `response_time` you can just do:

```
awk '{split($2,a,"_");print a[2],$(NF-1)}' file
```

---

Or just:

```
awk -F" |_"  '{print $3,$7}' file
US 1000
UK 60
```